# Show external sources from jar package in jacoco report

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

We use in our java project jacoco with the gradle-plugin to calculate the coverage.
The problem is we put our classes which were generated from an XML in an extra project and resolved it as a dependency. We want the codecoverage of these model classes too to analyze it. To check if we used all setter methods of the datacontainers in our mapper classes. Do the code coverage in the model project is not an option.

Currently jacoco only shows in the report (html/xml/csv) only our classes which is in the main project but not the classes of external jars. The jacoco session contains the coverage data when I load it with eclipse or intellij.

```
buildscript {
... 
    dependencies {
    ...     
        classpath 'externalpackage:externalpackage-model'
    ...
    }   
}

compile('externalpackage:externalpackage-model:0.0.8')  
testCompile('externalpackage:externalpackage-model:tests@jar')
testCompile('externalpackage:externalpackage-model:0.0.8:sources@jar')

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"        
}   

additionalSourceDirs files('externalpackage:externalpagage:0.0.8:sources@jar')
//Doesn't work either
//additionalSourceDirs files('C:/Users/sero/Downloads/test/externalpackage-0.0.8-sources')
//additionalSourceDirs = files('C:/Users/sero/Downloads/test/externalpackage-0.0.8-sources/de/mycompany/.../MyModelClasses.java')
}
```

The jar source package is like this:
(root)/de/mycompany/.../MyModelClasses.java

Maybe someone has an idea

Comment: You are talking about putting _"our classes which were **generated** from an XML"_ into the jacoco-report. Usually, you want to _exclude_ generated classes from all kind of code analysis, because if it's generated you can't change anything even if coverage is low. And: generated classes usually are just data-containers, and don't provide any logic - testing (and calculating coverage from) getters/setters is not of much use.

Comment: That's right that data classes don't needed to be tested. But the requirement for this problem is a little bit different. We need to validate that all our tests are using the setter Methods of these data containers. With that we want to validate that we didn't forget to set any fields in the mapper classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it by myself. Problem was, you need to specify the path the the classes too.

I unzipped the jars into the build folder and added additionalClassDirs and additionalSourceDirs to the report job.

This is the buildfile.

```
configurations {
    externalClasses 
    externalSources
}

dependencies {
    externalClasses "externalpackage:externalpackage-model:0.0.8@jar"
    externalSources "externalpackage:externalpackage-model:0.0.8:sources@jar"        
    ...
}

buildscript {
... 
    dependencies {
    ...     
        classpath 'externalpackage:externalpackage-model'
    ...
    }   
}

compile('externalpackage:externalpackage-model:0.0.8')  
testCompile('externalpackage:externalpackage-model:tests@jar')
testCompile('externalpackage:externalpackage-model:0.0.8:sources@jar')

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

task unzipExternalModel(type: Copy){
    from zipTree(configurations.externalSources.files.first())
    into "$buildDir/tmp/externalSources"
    from zipTree(configurations.externalClasses.files.first())
    into "$buildDir/tmp/externalClasses"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn unzipExternalModel
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"        
    }   
    additionalSourceDirs = files("$buildDir/tmp/externalSources")
    additionalClassDirs = files("$buildDir/tmp/externalClasses") 
}
```

Comment: Note, in order to get source output I had to split the copy task into two (it's not made to support setting `into` twice)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, using 7.1.1, this code (inpired on the Vincent's) works:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    jacoco {
        includes = ["com.mycompany.**"]
        includeNoLocationClasses true
    }
}

task unzipLibrariesJar(type: Copy){
    into "$buildDir/tmp/libClasses"
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath
            .filter { it.path.contains("mycompany") }
            .collect {zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

task unzipLibrariesSrc(type: Copy){
    into "$buildDir/tmp/libSources"
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath
                .filter { it.path.contains("mycompany") &&  new File(it.getPath().replace(".jar", "-sources.jar")).exists() }
                .collect { new File(it.getPath().replace(".jar", "-sources.jar")) }
                .collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    dependsOn unzipLibrariesJar
    dependsOn unzipLibrariesSrc
    reports {
        html.enabled true
    }
    additionalClassDirs.from = files("$buildDir/tmp/libClasses")
    additionalSourceDirs.from = files("$buildDir/tmp/libSources")
}
```

Note that, I am only interested on the logs from all classes of "com.mycompany" package. You should change this according to your requirements.